# JML postcondition contains class method call

Tags: java, contracts, jml, post-conditions

Can a JML postcondition for a class method contain a call to another method call

For example I have this class:

```
public class A
{
    public int doA(x)
    { ... }

    public int doB(int x, int y)
    { ... }
}
```

For the postcondition of doB can I have: `ensures doA(x) = doA(y)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, provided the called method doesn't include side effects and is declared as pure:

> The /*@ pure @*/ comment indicates that peek() is a pure method. A
>   pure method is one that doesn't have side effects. JML only allows
>   assertions to use pure methods. We declare peek() to be pure so it can
>   be used in the postcondition of pop(). If JML allowed non-pure methods
>   in assertions then we could inadvertently write specifications that
>   had side effects. This could result in code that works when compiled
>   with assertion checking enabled but doesn't work when assertion
>   checking is disabled.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jml/index.html

```
public class A
{
    public /*@ pure @*/ int doA(int x)
    { ... }

    //@ requires ...
    //@ ensures doA(x) == doA(y)
    public int doB(int x, int y)
    { ... }
}
```